# Nginx configuration file looking for default file in sites/enabled

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I seem to have an error when I lint my nginx.conf file. Here is what I have done:

1. Created a custom server block file named fn_django and placed it in nginx/sites-available.
2. Copied this file to /nginx/sites-enabled
3. Symlinked the two files

My nginx.conf file has these lines under Virtual Host Configs

```
##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

In my /sites-enabled directory I have two files:

- default // this one is empty
- fn_django // this contains the server block configurations

Why is my nginx linter then complaining of the following error?

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
```

Comment: Have you perhaps left a symlink in `sites-enabled` that points to a non-existent file? And, I am not sure what you mean by steps (2) and (3) - you should either copy the file or symlink it - not both.

Comment: Step 2 was copying my `nginx-conf` file to the directory `/sites-available/fn_django_nginx`

Step 3 was then creating a symlink link between the `/sites-available/fn_django_nginx` and `/sites-enabled/fn_django_nginx`

I checked if the symlink between /sites-available/fn_django_nginx and /sites-enabled/fn_django_nginx exists and it does exist

I'll check if there is a symlink to the non-existent `default` file. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @RichardSmith I found this symlink: 


`/sites-enabled/default` --> `/sites-available/default`

`/sites-available/default` does not exist. But I don't need it. Is there a way to tell my `nginx.conf` to only look for the `fn_django_nginx` file instead of `default`?

Comment: Remove the symlink or create an empty file in `sites-available`. For example `touch /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`